# Playing and pausing music player in WP 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have an application (Windows Phone 8.1 RT) in which I record and play small audio clips. I record the clips using `MediaCapture` object and play them using `MediaElement` control's `Play()` and `Pause()` methods.

However, if the phone's music player is playing some music in the background, it creates a couple of issues for me:

1. During recording audio, the playing music is muted so that the recorded audio doesn't have the content of the music being played in the background. I'd like to pause the background music when I start recording and resume it when the recording stops. How can I do this?
2. During playing the audio, the music playing in the background is stopped when my recorded audio clip is played, but it doesn't resume automatically when the audio clip finishes or is paused. In fact, the music being played is removed from the quick launch (the dropdown you get when volume key is pressed) and can only be resumed from music player.

How can I access the phone's music player so that I can explicity pause and resume it when the user is playing/pausing the audio clips in my app?